# Convert the two rectangular (Cartesian) points to polar coordinates with $r > 0 $and$0 ≤ θ < 2π.$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

(a) Convert the two rectangular (Cartesian) points to polar coordinates with $r > 0 $and$0 ≤ θ < 2π.$

$(4,-4)$ and $(-1,\sqrt 3)$

(b) Convert the two polar points to rectangular (Cartesian) coordinates.

$(-1,\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $(6,-\frac{5\pi}{4})$

(c) Sketch the set of points $\left\{ (r,\theta ):1\le r\le 4,\frac { \pi }{ 4 } \le \theta \le \frac { 3\pi }{ 4 }  \right\} $

**My attempt**

a) for $(4,-4)$ = $(r,\theta)$= $(4\sqrt 2,-\frac{\pi}{4})$

for $(-1,\sqrt 3)$ = $(r,\theta)$= $( 2,-\frac{\pi}{3})$

b)for $(-1,\frac{\pi}{2})$ = $(x,y)$ = $(0,1)$

for $(6,-\frac{5\pi}{4})$ = $(x,y)$ = $(-3\sqrt 3,-3\sqrt 3)$

Please verify my answers and also explain me how to do c)

Comment: I don't understand why it asks you sketch a set of infinitesimal points. Is it asking for a region shaded?

Comment: Your angle in the second point of (a) is wrong (you also want the first angle to be between the given values). I think your first one in part (b) is right, but it is not good practice to have a negative radius. Your second part of (b) is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that

> b)for $(-1,\frac{\pi}{2})$ = $(x,y)$ = $(0,1)$

it is strange that for r a negative value is given, but it should be $(0,-1)$.

For that

> for $(6,-\frac{5\pi}{4})$ = $(x,y)$ = $(-3\sqrt 3,-3\sqrt 3)$

it should be $y>0$ and also $6\neq(54)^\frac12$.

To plot the region for part "c" let consider the boundaries: the two circles centered at the origin with radius $1$ and $4$ and the rays from the origin for $\theta=\pi/4$ and $\theta=3\pi/4$.

See for example for $2\le r\le 3$ and $\frac76\pi \le \theta \le \frac43 \pi$

[image]

Comment: can you please explain how to plot the graph. Where to substitute $\theta$ and $r$

Comment: @tienlee You simply need to draw the two circle and the two rays for the angles, the region is the area between the two circle and the two rays.

Comment: So, I need to substitute the values of $r$ and $\theta$ in $x=rcos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$

Comment: @tienlee take  alook to that example here https://media1.shmoop.com/images/calculus/calc_fn_polcord_narr_graphik_33.png You need to make a similar plot with your values

Answer (score 0):

You want to change your $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ in $$(4\sqrt 2,-\frac{\pi}{4})$$ to an angle between $0$ and $2\pi $

Similarly for the  $$( 2,-\frac{\pi}{3})$$